# Using additional Saveables in Eclipse AbstractTextEditor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a textual editor that extends AbstractTextEditor and I also have an Outline that needs to be saved when its content is modified by the user. I am currently using a `Saveable` which is added to the editor.

If the editor was marked as 'dirty' and it is saved, the `Saveable`is saved as well. However, if the `Saveable`'s state changes to 'dirty', the * next to the file name does not appear. The save button in the top menu bar does show, but when I click it, nothing happens.

This is my implementation:

```
public class MyTextEditor extends AbstractTextEditor {
    ...

    public void setOutlineSaveable(Saveable saveable) {
        this.outlineSaveable = saveable;
        ISaveablesLifecycleListener lifecycleListener = (ISaveablesLifecycleListener)getSite().getService(ISaveablesLifecycleListener.class);
        lifecycleListener.handleLifecycleEvent( new SaveablesLifecycleEvent(this, SaveablesLifecycleEvent.POST_OPEN, new Saveable[] {saveable}, false));
    }

    @Override
    public Saveable[] getSaveables() {
        if(outlineSaveable != null) {
        // copy Saveables from super.getSaveables() to a new array
        Saveable[] superSaveables = super.getSaveables();
        Saveable[] res = new Saveable[superSaveables.length + 1];

        int i = 0;
        for(; i < superSaveables.length; i++) {
            res[i] = superSaveables[i];
        }

        res[i] = outlineSaveable;
        return res; 
    }
    else
      return super.getSaveables();
    }

    public void saveableDirty() {
        firePropertyChange(PROP_DIRTY);
    }
}
```

My ContentOutlinePage:

```
public class GraphicalOutlinePage extends ContentOutlinePage {
    ...

    private GraphicalOutlineSaveable saveable;

    public Saveable getSaveable() {
        return saveable;
    }

class GraphicalOutlineSaveable extends Saveable {

    private boolean dirty = false;
    private IEditorPart editor;

    public GraphicalOutlineSaveable(IEditorPart editor) {
        this.editor = editor;    
    }

    @Override
    public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        viewer.doSave(monitor);
        dirty = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.err.println("GraphicalOutline.GraphicalOutlineSaveable.equals");
        return obj instanceof GraphicalOutlineSaveable && ((Saveable)obj).getName() == getName();
    }

    @Override
    public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor() {
        return editor.getEditorInput().getImageDescriptor();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Graphical Outline: " + editor.getEditorInput().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDirty() {
        System.err.println("GraphicalOutlinePage.GraphicalOutlineSaveable.isDirty: " + dirty);
        return dirty;
    }

    public void setDirty() {
        System.err.println("GraphicalOutlinePage.GraphicalOutlineSaveable.setDirty");
        dirty = true;

        // notify text editor about property change
        if(editor instanceof AbstractTextEditor) {
            ((MyTextEditor)editor).saveableDirty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return viewer.hashCode();
    }
}
}
```

`viewer`is a `GraphicalViewer`displayed in the `ContentOutlinePage`.

Somewhere in another class, I then call:

```
textEditor.setSaveable(grOutlinePage.getSaveable());
```

Comment: You probably need to override the editor `isDirty()` method and test all the Saveables for dirty.

Comment: That solved my problem, could you post it as an answer please? (I thought using the Saveables would avoid the necessity to override isDirty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to override the main editor `isDirty()` method and test each of the `Saveable` objects dirty flags.

It seems that the handling of multiple Saveables is not done as cleanly is it might have been.